# How can I get the cartesian product in Oracle SQL of the result of a string split with all entries in an array both being keys in a JSON object?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, json-table

How can I get the cartesian product of the result of a string split with all entries in an array both being keys in a JSON object? This was the closest I got to the answer

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(scp, '[^ ]+', 1, level), aud
  FROM (SELECT scp, aud
           FROM JSON_TABLE('{
                              "s": "s1 s2 s3",
                              "a": [
                                "a1",
                                "a2",
                                "a3"
                              ]
                            }' FORMAT JSON,
            '$[*]' COLUMNS(
                            scp VARCHAR2 PATH '$.s',
                            NESTED PATH '$.a[*]'
                            COLUMNS(
                                     aud VARCHAR2 PATH '$[*]'
                                   )
                            )
                            )
        )
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(scp, '[^ ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
```

but it is only exploding each `s` for `a1`. I am looking to get 9 entries, mapping each `s` to each `a`. How can this be achieved with a single `JSON_TABLE` query?

Comment: The issue is due to missing quote(`"`) followed by `a2`, eg. currently JSON value is wrong. You can add `AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL AND PRIOR aud = aud` to the end of the statement after fixing it [Demo-->](https://dbfiddle.uk/J5vgGtEa)

Comment: It cannot be achieved by `json_table` because `a1 s2 s3` has nothing to do with JSON. These are two different tasks: split string and JSON table

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split a string using JSON functions.

You can split the string using simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions) and a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (scp, aud, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT scp,
         aud,
         1,
         INSTR(scp, ' ', 1)
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           '{"s": "s1 s2 s3","a": ["a1","a2","a3"]}' FORMAT JSON,
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS(
             scp VARCHAR2 PATH '$.s',
             NESTED PATH '$.a[*]' COLUMNS(
               aud VARCHAR2 PATH '$[*]'
             )
           )
         )
UNION ALL
  SELECT scp,
         aud,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(scp, ' ', epos + 1)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(scp, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(scp, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS scp,
       aud
FROM   rsqfc;
```

From Oracle 12, you could also use `CROSS APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(scp, '[^ ]+', 1, lvl) AS scp,
       aud
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"s": "s1 s2 s3","a": ["a1","a2","a3"]}' FORMAT JSON,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           scp VARCHAR2 PATH '$.s',
           NESTED PATH '$.a[*]' COLUMNS(
             aud VARCHAR2 PATH '$[*]'
           )
         )
       )
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(scp, '[^ ]+')
       );
```

Which both output:

| SCP | AUD |
| --- | --- |
| s1 | a1 |
| s1 | a2 |
| s1 | a3 |
| s2 | a1 |
| s2 | a2 |
| s2 | a3 |
| s3 | a1 |
| s3 | a2 |
| s3 | a3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n_6eJ4QP)